# jquery not selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do in the following way 
select the parent class "search-result-item" and skip the h3 tag in it and btn-grey class from selection. my code is here

```
$('div.search-result-item:not(h3 .btn-grey)').click(function(e){
    console.log('1');
});
```

but it selects h3 and btn-grey also what i  doing wrong?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for it ?

Comment: Post the HTML that this applies to in your question.

Comment: is your `.btn-grey` inside your `h3`? or are they the same element?

Comment: Typical question where answer could be find in few seconds if it was clearly asked... But not!

Comment: h3 .btn-grey are child of search-result-item

Comment: HTML is here http://pastebin.com/9jXKNH6m

Comment: I have solved it using
$('div.search-result-item').click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is("h3, btn-grey")){
        console.log('1');
    }
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$('div.search-result-item').find(":not('h3'),:not('.btn-grey')")
```

or a better solution as wolf suggested,

```
$('div.search-result-item :not("h3,.btn-grey")')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what OP is looking for, want to exclude both or what?! (of course, i din't downvoted your answer)

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah op is trying to exclude the both..

Comment: OP edited question, they are children, so it should be indeed: `$('div.search-result-item :not("h3,.btn-grey")')`

Comment: I have already tried in the way before posting the question

Comment: @Shahbaz you should post your html structure inorder to get the answer you want.. or please make a demo of it...

Comment: I have pasted the Html http://pastebin.com/9jXKNH6m

Answer (score 0):

Try so:

```
$('div.search-result-item').not('h3 .btn-grey').click(function(e){
    console.log('1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look on ":has()" selector, http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/ .

```
$("div.search-result-item:not(:has(h3.btn-grey)")
```